# Integrate with Telerik Nativescript

Tags: angular, typescript, deepstream.io

I am trying to integrate deepstream.io with NativeScript but I am not able to get it to work successfully.

There is also no sample code about integration between NativeScript and deepstream.io.

I am wondering if it is possible for deepstream.io to work with Nativescript.

Integrate with Angular 2 works perfectly as there is sample code I can make use of.

thanks
Sam Liaw

Answer (score 0):

not familiar with NativeScript but from a quick look it appears to be just javascript and appears you can use npm modules with it.

Is there any specific error you're getting?

We have tutorials [1] with most major mobile frameworks and can't image why it wouldn't work with NativeScript.

[1. Deepstream tutorials](https://deepstreamhub.com/tutorials/#tutorials)

Answer (score 0):

Integrating with Nativescript shouldn't be an issue as the way you refer a community contributed library in NPM ecosystem don't varies much and as far as Native-JS mobile app frameworks(React Native and Nativescript) are considered it's a matter of construct, and where lifecycle event hooks are provided to initialize and later re-use a library.

What goes inside a `Constructor` and `componentDidMount` for React Native can easily go inside `app.js` before `application.start()`(initialization) and `loaded`(post-initialization usage) events for NativeScript and looks like https://deepstream.io/tutorials/integrations/frontend-reactnative/ could be a little bit helpful